# Google contacts api retrieve a single contact using php missing group info

Tags: php, google-contacts-api, google-shared-contacts

I'm puzzled by this one.

When I retrieve all contacts it does return the contacts groups (only the custom groups, not the system groups). But when I only retrieve a single contact I don't get the groups back.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_single_contact

In this example XML return, it does include the contact groups in the `gContact:groupMembershipInfo` item. But when pulling a request in my contact list, I do get all the info, but not the groups. Is this an error in the v3.0 API? Or am I making a huge mistake?

I use the google PHP wrapper

My stored contact has a google id (which has a http in stead of https address).

`$url = str_replace( 'http://', 'https://', $stored_contact['google_id'] )."?alt=json";
        $req = new Google_HttpRequest($url);
        $val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);
        $rawcontact = json_decode($val->getResponseBody(), true);`

It returns the contact as expected, but does not include the groups...

Any suggestions are highly appriciated!

Regards,

Parsec